# IE ierror with parsing html

Tags: visual-studio-2010, html-parsing

i get this error HTML Parsing Error: Unable to modify the parent container element before the child element is closed (KB927917) when try to run my project in visual studio 2010.

but ONLY when run in virtual mashine!
otherwise same source code doesn't yield same error

NOTE: IE 8 Advance settings are same for both configurations!

help

Comment: Paste the HTML so we can see what's causing the error.

Comment: it doesn't say it says: line:0, char:0

Comment: and html/js source doesn't return error unles in VM envoronment.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you read [KB927917](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/927917)? It describes the situation quite well; it's a more helpful error message than the “Operation aborted” we used to get, anyway. See [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/ie/archive/2008/04/23/what-happened-to-operation-aborted.aspx) blog for more background on what it means.

It's not directly connected to virtual-machine or not; what you have is a race condition, where a script can load too early and try to manipulate elements that haven't been fully loaded by IE's HTML parser yet. Race conditions are inherently difficult to pin down as factors like being in a VM or how fast the server is responding can affect whether the error occurs or not.

You need to narrow down which script is responsible by commenting all the `<script>` elements out and adding them back in one-by-one until you get the error. Then you need to delay the operation of whatever that script is doing, for example by moving it into a `window.onload` event handler.